# Error generating Gradle in Eclipse ADT

Tags: android, eclipse, gradle, adt, android-studio

I have an android project which I built in Eclipse, and I wish to migrate it to Android Studio. Even though Android Studio works fine without gradle build files, I want to create them using Eclipse ADT as explained [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/migrate.html).

However, when trying to generate the Gradle files, Eclipse shows me the error log as soon as I click on "Finish". I have tried to decode what it means but to no avail.

Here is the error in question:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.runInCurrentThread(ModalContext.java:477)
at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.run(ModalContext.java:372)
at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.run(WizardDialog.java:1028)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.wizards.exportgradle.GradleExportPage.generateBuildfiles(GradleExportPage.java:293)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.wizards.exportgradle.GradleExportWizard.performFinish(GradleExportWizard.java:32)
at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.finishPressed(WizardDialog.java:827)
at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.buttonPressed(WizardDialog.java:432)
at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog$2.widgetSelected(Dialog.java:624)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:248)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4169)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3758)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:825)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:801)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.WizardHandler$Export.executeHandler(WizardHandler.java:103)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.WizardHandler.execute(WizardHandler.java:279)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerProxy.execute(HandlerProxy.java:290)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.E4HandlerProxy.execute(E4HandlerProxy.java:76)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:56)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invokeUsingClass(InjectorImpl.java:231)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invoke(InjectorImpl.java:212)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.invoke(ContextInjectionFactory.java:131)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceImpl.executeHandler(HandlerServiceImpl.java:171)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.LegacyHandlerService.executeCommand(LegacyHandlerService.java:515)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.actions.CommandAction.runWithEvent(CommandAction.java:157)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:584)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:501)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:411)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4169)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3758)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1053)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:942)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:86)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:588)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:543)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.wizards.exportgradle.BuildFileCreator.appendDependencies(BuildFileCreator.java:368)
        at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.wizards.exportgradle.BuildFileCreator.createBuildFiles(BuildFileCreator.java:217)
        at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.wizards.exportgradle.GradleExportPage$6.run(GradleExportPage.java:274)
        at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.runInCurrentThread(ModalContext.java:464)
        ... 58 more
```

Anyone have any idea what this means? The code compiles fine and runs both in eclipse and in Android Studio (without gradle), which is why I'm dumbfounded, surely there isn't anything wrong in my source code to cause the error

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. I was able to get around it by manually creating an empty "settings.gradle" file in the root of the project I was trying to export. I also had to create it for any other dependent projects (i.e. any modules that show up on the "Exported Modules" area of the export screen).

Hope this helps.